# Converting attachment format form MTOM to DIME

Tags: web-services, cxf, mtom

I am trying to send the attachment . Currently I am using the CXF webservice which supports MTOM format but I need to send the attachment in DIME .

Please refer the code snippet:-

```
   Works fine:

     USDWebService ss = new USDWebService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    USDWebServiceSoap port = ss.getUSDWebServiceSoap();


      The problem Area this is the code given by my client to interact with their    system :

       ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub)port)._setProperty(Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT,
            Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT_DIME);
        ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) port).addAttachment(dhandler);
```

The above code snippet dosent work as CXF webservice dosent support     org.apache.axis.client.Stub so how do I send my attachment through CXF.

Answer (score 0):

DIME has long since bean deprecated.   CXF does not support DIME, just MTOM.    If you need to do DIME, you'll need to use something other than CXF.

Comment: So is their any intermediate format to which we can convert like:                    operation MTOM --> Some common format -->DIME